# issue adding a class to a dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

I have some elements that get created on the fly via a plugin I am using, and I want to give a class to a certain `div` if it is the only div.

If I write conditional that alerts if there is one element, it works (the alert shows up), but if I try to assign a class to it it does not get assigned:

alert code (works)

```
if ( $('#carousel > div').length == 1 ) {
    alert('code');
}
```

class code (does NOT work)

```
if ( $('#carousel > div').length == 1 ) {
    $(this).addClass('code');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is what you think it is. a `if` block does not change the execution context(`this`) - `this` inside the `if` block will still refer to the same object as it was referring outside the `if` block, so `this` inside the `if` block may not be referring to the `div`

```
if ( $('#carousel > div').length == 1 ) {
    $('#carousel > div').addClass('code');
}
```

Comment: This works. Why doesn't `$(this)` work? I don't get it.

Comment: @BlekStena it boils down to what `this` is referring to

Answer (score 3):

In your context `$(this)` does not points the required elements that you want.

Try,

```
var cache =  $('#carousel > div');
if (cache.length == 1 ) {
    cache.addClass('code');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And at all, the `if` is useless because jQuery can handle "empty" objects. So what you really need is:

`$('#carousel > div').addClass('code');`

If `$('#carousel > div').length` is `0`, nothing will happen.